# woocommerce add fee to cart based on quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wan to add fee based on quantity.
For eg: If quantity in cart = 5 , then the fee to be added should be 4$,
              If quantity in cart = 7, then the fee to be added should be 8$

I have tried this code to get quantity.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'woocommerce_custom_surcharge');

function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;
$amount =  $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_item_quantities();
if($amount==5)
{
    $excost = 7;
    }
    else if($amount==7){
    $excost = 8;
    }
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Charges delivery', $excost, $taxable = false, $tax_class = '');
}
```

Please help with the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Try this

```
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge(){ 
global $woocommerce;
//Getting Cart Contents. 
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
//Calculating Quantity
foreach($cart as $cart_val => $cid){
        $qty += $cid['quantity']; 
    }
//Your Condition
if($qty==5)
{
    $excost = 7;
    }
    else if($qty==7){
    $excost = 8;
    }

    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Charges delivery', $excost, $taxable = false, $tax_class = '');


}
```

[From Here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-excelling-ecommerce-woocommerce-total-cart-weight) I found that We need to get the quantity of the cart by summing up the values of the cart.Hope this will Solve your problem.