# woocommerce custom price in checkout and cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using woocommerce in my wordpress site. I need a provision where the customer can able to change the price in the cart page & checkout page.

And i have tired this code

```
function action_woocommerce_before_cart_totals(  ) { 
 global $woocommerce;

 $woocommerce->cart->total  = $woocommerce->cart->total;
   var_dump( $woocommerce->cart->total);};
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear and not detailed… what does mean "I need a provision"… How can the customer can change the price?

Comment: it is something like customer can enter custom donation amount

Comment: Please check the following link this might help you
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648174/woocommerce-add-fee-to-cart-based-on-quantity/20650123#20650123)

Comment: @ashokkumarn12 You mean add extra fee in cart & checkout page?